# How to plot the graph for parameter vs x variable?

Tags: matlab

I'm trying to plot the graph for a parameter vs x variable. I used Matlab software. But I did not get a graph that I want. Is there anything wrong with my code? Here I attached the parameter value and Matlab code that I used. Hope someone can help me.[image]

[image]

Comment: So, what is the figure it gives?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way you write your code, MATLAB will think that `D` is just a number that is, when all is said and done, set to `0.13`. You probably want it to be an array to align with the values in the `x` array. So I suggest that you, in each `for` loop, change `D =` to `D(i) =`.

Comment: Thank you so much. I have followed your suggestion and I got the figure that I want.